# how do I stop a timer when the app gets into the background or user exits the app

Tags: ios, swift, timer

how would I go about to stop a timer when the user exits out of the app, clicks the power button, or gets sent to the background, I realize we can listen to Darwin calls but I do not know how to go about with that.

here's an example from the log out put:

at update 2 I shut the phone off, then at update 6 I turn it on and open the app

```
1
-LuylG6CvCZNSkLruq9N
updated
2
-LuylG6CvCZNSkLruq9N
2019-11-30 20:17:36.400772-0500 Score[5044:1122736] Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 13 (0xd), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
updated
3
-LuylG6CvCZNSkLruq9N
updated
4
-LuylG6CvCZNSkLruq9N
updated
5
-LuylG6CvCZNSkLruq9N
updated
6
Fatal error: Index out of range
2019-11-30 20:17:42.889365-0500 Score[5044:1122736] Fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb)
```

Comment: the platform is iOS

Comment: Timers don’t run when the app is in the background or when the screen is off or when the app isn’t running, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have a process that runs on a timer to always update it, and when the phone is turned off it keeps the timer running and updating, and then because the other process stop it'll crash the app due to "index out of range"

Comment: I threw in a log and updated the question to reflect this

Comment: so Xcode allows the app to continue to run even when the device is turned off, and for the "index out of range" it updates perfectly fine all throughout the app but when I turn the phone off it crashes.

Comment: ah ok, that makes since.

Comment: for the "Array out of bound" what are you doing to trigger it?

Comment: im not sure. it has the process repeat every second. that's why Im trying to disable the timer

Comment: have you tried and checked for an empty array and see if that helps?

Comment: how would I go with that exactly?

Comment: where ever you reference the array, check and see if its empty. for example, make a table view take its data and display it

Comment: would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: sure, ill provide it as an answer.

Comment: In answer to your question, you can cancel timers in [`applicationWillResignActive(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive) or [`sceneWillResignActive(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197919-scenewillresignactive) or in response to [`willResignActiveNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622973-willresignactivenotification) notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an example on how how'd check:

```
    if(data.isEmpty == false){
    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
```

Comment: oh my god you are so awesome. thank you so much for the help!!!!!